# How do I replace "$id" with a value?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

How do I replace "$id" with a value?
I need to replace the regular expression in the sql string with a value.
I'm trying to use RegExp.

```js
const src = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=$id";
const myFind = "$id";
// $id is the property of the object. example { $id: 123,}
const find = new RegExp(myFind, 'g');
const repl = 123;

const _completeSQL = src.replace( find, repl);
console.log(`_completeSQL ${_completeSQL}`);
```

My attempt fails because $ is a regular expression.

Comment: `$` is a special character in regular expressions - you need to escape it.

Comment: Thanks to the function escapeRegExp, I really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Like @CertainPerformance has said, you need to use a backslash to escape `$` in a regular expression. You should also use `\b` to match a word boundary so that other words starting with `id` won't match. In other words, you should do:

```
const myFind = "\\$id\\b";
```

or:

```
const myFind = /\$id\b/;
```

Note that if you choose to use double-quotes to enclose your regular expression, you will need to use double-backslashes to denote one backslash, so that what follows the backslash can be properly escaped when evaluated as a regular expression.

Comment: Thank you for reminding "to match a word boundary". I missed this moment.
But when the parameter \ b is added, the code breaks.